# Reading MS Office documents on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ms-office

My mission is to create an iOS Cocoa application where documents like .pdf, .doc, .xsl would be read inside my application.

Because I will create the application for my country's government the main requirement is security. The client wants all documents to be read inside my app, loading the documents in third-party applications is not allowed.

I know that iOS has a container for PDF files, but I don't know any frameworks on iOS that can read Microsoft Office formats. Any tips?

Comment: You should say Cocoa/Objective-C instead of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of open-source, free as well as paid libraries for displaying and editing Microsoft content in Cocoa and CocoaTouch.

However, if you're using iOS you can display (not edit) Microsoft documents (.doc, .xls, .dot) as well as PDF files in a UIWebView.

Simply like this:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];    
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: According to OP : ` client wants all documents to be readen exactly in my app. So the way when this documents will be opened with 3d party application - cant be used`

Comment: @AKV Yup, as opposed to "registering a URL and sending the data to another app", was the way I interpreted the question. . Did I get it right?

Comment: If i will user UIWebView - it means that document in the fact wil be opened by Safari? The moost important thing of my task is to completely isolate from other application and prevent possible information loss.

Comment: @Mariya29 : That is what i wanted to say, but people shut my mouth by giving down votes.

Comment: @Mariya29 No, it won't be opened by Safari, it will be using a sand-boxed process within your App. It may use some of the underlying framework that Safari uses to render content, however Apple is constantly updating security on this (eg JS by default only has 5 secs to run). . . whether this is right for you or not, I can't say.

Comment: Thank you both for sharing this knowledges with me, looks like this way should be secured enough for me.

Comment: @JasperBlues, I have almost the same problem, but failed to find any library for the task (UIWebView cannot be used due to its bad rendering). Could you give me a link to open-source library or name any paid one?